# Spring boot application not working with external tomcat8 server installed in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I Created a spring boot application. I Changed the packaging to war and deployed in my local tomcat server, it is working fine. But if I take that war and place in ubuntu tomcat server, my application is not working

I want the war to work in ubuntu tomcat server. Are there any configurations to be changed in that server?

Error was:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Apr 20 06:08:48 UTC 2019
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Could not initialize class demo.config.CreateSessionFactory

**Mysql 5.7, JDK 1.8, tomcat 8.5.6**

Here is my pom.xml code

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
     <properties>
          <start-class>demo.MainApplication</start-class>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties> 
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>
<build>
    <finalName>sanjay</finalName>
</build>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/annotations -->
<dependency>

    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>


<!-- 
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging> -->
</project>
```

Comment: Please check logs of your tomcat. It should be somewhere in `/var/log/tomcat8`.  Probably error should be in `catalina.out`. Then if you find an exception in logs, then add it to the question.

Comment: The first thing is you should never mix spring boot version cause your parent has `1.5.6.RELEASE` and the spring-boot-starter-log is `1.3.8.RELEASE` furthermore I would reconsider to use Spring Boot 1.X cause it's announced already that end of Life for August 2019 (https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019). So I would suggest to work in Spring Boot 2.x only.